# Get Element in Div JS

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

I want to create an onclick function for button that is in div with id `Restyled`.

I tried this:

```
<script>
var RestyledDiv = document.querySelector("#Restyled");
var RestyledButton = x.querySelector("button");
RestyledButton.onclick = function() {
   alert("button was clicked");
}​;​
</script>
```

But I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: Did you define `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for adding an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the button and you can use the `querySelector` to go deeper than just a single selector level.

You also had two hidden whitespace characters in your code that resulted in the syntax error you were seeing.

[image]

Note the `<0x200b>` characters that are shown in my editor that is configured to show whitespace characters.

```js
var RestyledButton = document.querySelector("#Restyled button");
RestyledButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
   alert("button was clicked");
});
```

```html
<div id="Restyled">
  <button>Click me!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i tried running your code and basically there are 2 things that i would like to point out:

1. var RestyledDiv = document.querySelector("#Restyled");
   it is not needed here, you are not using the given div.
   You can directly select the button by the provided id. You can delete the dive query line whatsoever.
2. it seems like there was something weird in your last line of code:
   }​;​

For some reason, it was not working for me, but as soon as i literally retyped the same code - it worked.

Here's how it works for me:

```
<script>
  var RestyledButton = document.querySelector('#restyledButton');
  RestyledButton.onclick = function () {
    alert('button was clicked');
  };
</script>
```